# MySQL Optimization: LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, left-join, inner-join

I have the following 3 tables:

**publications** (primary key = *article*)

```
article | title | pubType
```

**authors** (primary key = *author_name*)

```
author_name | author_somethingelse
```

**pub_author_map**

```
article | author_name
```

Given a value for `pubType`, I need to select information about the articles, including authors.  To do this, I have

```
SELECT p.article, p.title, p.dateTime, pam.author_name FROM publications p 
LEFT JOIN pub_author_map pam ON pam.article = p.article
LEFT JOIN authors a ON a.author_name = pam.author_name
WHERE p.pubType = '$pubType' ORDER BY p.article LIMIT 10
```

Even with a `LIMIT 10`, this query clocked in at about 29s.  There are 1500 rows in `publications` and 3000 rows in `pub_author_map`.

**How can I optimize the above query?**

Comment: Note that LIMIT does not limit the sql data set but the output. Therefore, it should not be used in production.

Comment: @SebastianHojas Are you saying LIMIT should not be used in production? ?

Comment: regarding your note:  it is generally much better to first come up with a query that delivers correct results, and then rewrite it to work fast than the other way around.  There's no reason to leave authors out of the example.  Most of us can handle three way joins.

Comment: @SebastianHojas But would adding `LIMIT` to the query decrease the time the query takes to finish?

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm convinced; question updated

Comment: @Adrian I'm serious. ´Limit´ should not be used in production, as it does simply waste computation time. A limit statement does decrease the amount of rows of the outputted result set, but not the result set itself.

Comment: @Blaine Most of the time it does not. It may, however, decrease the time which is needed to output/parse the result.

Comment: @SebastianHojas hmm interesting, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add indicies

- pub_author_map on column article
- publications on column pubType

for example like this.

```
CREATE INDEX pub_author_idx_1 
    ON pub_author_map (article);

CREATE INDEX publications_idx_1
    ON publications (pubType);
```

Comment: This could be but later you save the time.

Comment: Since `p` is also being sorted on `article`, it needs a composite index on `pubType` (for selection) and `article` (for ordering) as follows:

`CREATE INDEX foo ON publications (pubType, article);`

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize tables by using indexes.. e.g. index columns which are used as foreign keys when retrieving data: here is good tutorial for indexing, `http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-index.php` indexes will take more disk space but they can save hours when you are doing queries to database with relatively much data inside.

Answer (score 1):

If an INNER JOIN gives correct results, use it.  Use LEFT JOIN only when you need the results it provides.

Do you ever want to see articles with no authors?

Comment: No, I do not want to see those; I was actually following OMG Ponies' approach at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151919/mysql-update-with-2-inner-joins-hangs